# Confused over how the eigenvalues were obtained in a question involving a second order polynomial

Tags: homework-and-exercises, eigenvalue

The characteristic equation is as follows:

$E^2-\hbar \omega E -\hbar^2\omega^2\alpha^2 = 0 $

The eigenvalues I get are $\frac{\hbar\omega(1\pm\sqrt{1+4\alpha^2})}{2}$, however, I am being told the solution is $E_{0}(\alpha) = \hbar\omega(1-\sqrt{1+\alpha^2})$ and $E_{1}(\alpha)=\hbar\omega(1+\sqrt{1+\alpha^2)}$

I can't see how they are getting rid of both the 4 in from of $\alpha^2$ and the denominator 2. At this point I am wondering the the provided solution is incorrect, which I hope is not the case, and there is some trick I am missing here.

Comment: I'm assuming you forgot to write an $=0$ at your equation. Are you sure there is not a factor of 2 in the linear term in the equation: $E^2-2\hbar\omega E-\hbar^2\omega^2\alpha^2=0$?

Comment: Apologies about that. No the hamiltonian I am given is $\hbar\omega \begin{bmatrix}0 & \alpha \\ \alpha & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given solution is wrong.  You can see this by taking the $\alpha = 0$ case of the provided Hamiltonian:
$$
H = \hbar \omega \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are obviously $0$ and $\hbar \omega$ (since the matrix is diagonal, we can just read off the eigenvalues.)  Your answer reduces to these values in the $\alpha = 0$ case, while the official answer reduces to $0$ and $2 \hbar \omega$.

This tactic, by the way, is generally quite useful in physics:  when faced with a discrepancy between two results, look for a simpler case where the answer is obvious and which will allow you to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Thank you for this. I got so caught up in trying to figure out what I did wrong as I assumed the question solution was right.